# XAMPP php include works, but the include is not loading the css

Tags: php, html, css, xampp

For maintaining and developing a website, I am going to run that website locally in an test environment on XAMPP. XAMPP is working fine, but when I try to include some html, the text displays but without the css. Pictures also wont load.
I checked through the settings of XAMPP, but didn't find anything. Is there some setting in XAMPP that I missed?
What makes me wonder about this is the fact that that exact same files are already running on production without any problem.

I am working with this include:

```
<?php
   header("content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
   include('html/frontpage.html');
?>
```

and this html include for the css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles.css">
```

Comment: It's likely the folder holding the CSS/Pictures are not accessible by apache due to folder permissions. Are you getting any php errors? when you open up console in the browser, are you seeing errors? When you open up developer tools in chrome, click the network section, find the resources in red that didn't load, click on their name and see the headers, previews, response tabs, what errors do you see if any?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, problem seemed that styles.css was loading from the parent-parent directory (for whatever reason) not from the parent dir. Removed all files from htdocs and just put the whole git below it. Fixed it for me.